# querying for rows in a table and displaying specific rows if they exist in another

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two different tables

[image]

And:

[image]

First i have used $timeapp_id which is the current user_id of the logged in user.

I want to display only the rows in user_info where $timeapp_id appears in timesheet_approver_1

So if my $timeapp_id is currently 8 then i should only get three rows displayed from user_info.

I have managed to get this part working with this code:

---

```
$data2b = "select * from user_info where timesheet_approver_1 = $timeapp_id";

$result2b = mysql_query($data2b);
while ($row2b = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2b)) {

$timesheet_approver_1 = $row2b['timesheet_approver_1'];
$timesheet_approver_2 = $row2b['timesheet_approver_2'];
$user_id2 = $row2b['user_id'];

//echo "( $timesheet_approver_1 / ";
//echo "$timesheet_approver_2 )";
echo "(($user_id2))";
```

---

So running this code gives me three rows from the table user_info where user_id is 5, 7 and 34.

This is where i am now stuck. What i want to do is only display the rows in time_data if the user_id in time_data matches the user_id in user_info

If this worked i should only see the rows in time_data where the user_id is 8, so only one row would be displayed.

How would i do this?

Thanks

David

Comment: Why with the `mysql_query` and the [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/)?

Comment: This was my attempt at present to get the code working, so to begin with i wanted to get something working then get it secure & bug free.

Comment: That's why injection bugs happen in the first place: People forget the second part. There are some things you should never do out of principle, the risks are way too high. If you look at the features of a [SQL vulnerability testing tool](http://sqlmap.org/), think about if you'd ever want any of those things to happen to one of your applications. [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and used properly it's a lot harder to introduce bugs like this.

Comment: Thanks I appreciate it I'll have a read of those sites.

Comment: Thanks for fixing the formatting Filipe Silva, will try and make it look better in the future, i appreciate it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the variable $data2b you can JOIN the table user_info with table time_data ON user_info.user_id = time_data.user_id first, and then you can give the parameter WHERE the user_info.timesheet_approver_1 = $timeapp_id

Comment: Hi i have got this wrong but im not sure how this code should be, i have got: $data2b = "JOIN user_info with table time_data ON user_info.user_id = time_data.user_id where timesheet_approver_1 = $timeapp_id";  can you help correct me please? Thanks

Comment: awesome thanks i see how you do i did get it working using an array which is what i wanted, thanks for helping me :)

Answer (score 0):

What i did was pass the data through an array. I had got the code close to working but fatally wrong and so was not working through the array this is the correct working code i have used as corrected by Barmar on this site:

[PHP array displaying last row values from table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20157103/php-array-displaying-last-row-values-from-table)

```
$array = array();

while ($row2b = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2b)) {

    $timesheet_approver_1 = $row2b['timesheet_approver_1'];
    $timesheet_approver_2 = $row2b['timesheet_approver_2'];

    $array[] = $row2b['user_id'];
}

$withComma = implode(", ", $array);
```