# PHP array displaying last row values from table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays

What i want to do is pull out all of the rows in the below table.

```
$timeapp_id (this is the users id stored from session)
```

If the users id is 8 then the returned values of `$withComma` should be "5 7 34"

What the problem is the line `echo $withComma;` which is inside the loop outputs the above value, but when `echo $withComma;` is outside the loop only the last value is returned so when i pass this through `$results4` only the last row (which is 34) is displayed.

How do i go about fixing this so that `echo $withComma;` outside of the loop displays all the results instead of the last row?

```
$data2b = "select * from user_info where timesheet_approver_1 = $timeapp_id";

$result2b = mysql_query($data2b);

while ($row2b = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2b)) {

    $timesheet_approver_1 = $row2b['timesheet_approver_1'];
    $timesheet_approver_2 = $row2b['timesheet_approver_2'];
    $user_id2 = $row2b['user_id'];

    $array = array(" ",$user_id2);

    $withComma = implode(" ",$array);

    echo $withComma;

}

echo "<br><br>($withComma)";

$results4 = mysql_query("select * from time_data where user_id in ( $withComma ) and status = 'Submitted' order by data_date desc limit $time_entry_display_rows;");
```

Comment: Thanks Kingkero for improving my formatting i'll try and make things look more organised when i post in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're overwriting the `$array` and `withComma` variables each time through the loop.

You need to accumulate your values in an array inside the loop, and then implode the whole array when the loop is done.

```
$array = array();

while ($row2b = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2b)) {

    $timesheet_approver_1 = $row2b['timesheet_approver_1'];
    $timesheet_approver_2 = $row2b['timesheet_approver_2'];

    $array[] = $row2b['user_id'];
}

$withComma = implode(", ", $array);
```